# Microchip dsPIC33FJ256GP710A from example code for comm via UART

Tags: c, string, uart, microchip

I am trying to have my system send out a signal over xbee using UART and I have a good link and I am communicating.

The code that I am using is supposed to output something whenever I press a button on the board.

The code below is supposed to output

- 'h' when 1 is pressed
- 'hello how are' when 2 is pressed
- '3' when 3 is pressed
- '4' when 4 is pressed

1,3,and 4 work flawlessly but when i press 2 all i get is 'o h e'. Why that is?

```
#include <p33FJ256GP710A.h>
#include "string.h"

_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRC);            // Internal FRC oscillator
_FOSC(FCKSM_CSECMD & OSCIOFNC_OFF  & POSCMD_NONE);  
                            // Clock Switching is enabled and Fail Safe 
Clock Monitor is disabled
                            // OSC2 Pin Function: OSC2 is Clock Output
                            // Primary Oscillator Mode: XT Crystanl


#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

unsigned char S3Flag, S4Flag, S5Flag, S6Flag;
const char A[] = {'hello', ' ', 'how', ' ', 'are'};
int i;


void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _U2RXInterrupt(void) {
    LATA = U2RXREG;
    IFS1bits.U2RXIF = 0;
}
void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _U2TXInterrupt(void) {
    IFS1bits.U2TXIF = 0;
}

void InitClock() {
    PLLFBD = 38;    // M = 40
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0; // N1 = 2
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;  // N2 = 2
    OSCTUN = 0;
    RCONbits.SWDTEN = 0;

    // Clock switch to incorporate PLL
    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);      // Initiate Clock Switch to 
                                                // FRC with PLL (NOSC=0b001)
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x01);      // Start clock switching
    while (OSCCONbits.COSC != 0b001);   // Wait for Clock switch to occur   

    while(OSCCONbits.LOCK != 1) {};
}

void InitUART2() {
    // This is an EXAMPLE, so brutal typing goes into explaining all bit sets

    // The HPC16 board has a DB9 connector wired to UART2, so we will
    // be configuring this port only

    // configure U2MODE
    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 0;  // Bit15 TX, RX DISABLED, ENABLE at end of func
    //U2MODEbits.notimplemented;    // Bit14
    U2MODEbits.USIDL = 0;   // Bit13 Continue in Idle
    U2MODEbits.IREN = 0;    // Bit12 No IR translation
    U2MODEbits.RTSMD = 0;   // Bit11 Simplex Mode
    //U2MODEbits.notimplemented;    // Bit10
    U2MODEbits.UEN = 0;     // Bits8,9 TX,RX enabled, CTS,RTS not
    U2MODEbits.WAKE = 0;    // Bit7 No Wake up (since we don't sleep here)
    U2MODEbits.LPBACK = 0;  // Bit6 No Loop Back
    U2MODEbits.ABAUD = 0;   // Bit5 No Autobaud (would require sending '55')
    U2MODEbits.URXINV = 0;  // Bit4 IdleState = 1  (for dsPIC)
    U2MODEbits.BRGH = 0;    // Bit3 16 clocks per bit period
    U2MODEbits.PDSEL = 0;   // Bits1,2 8bit, No Parity
    U2MODEbits.STSEL = 0;   // Bit0 One Stop Bit

    // Load a value into Baud Rate Generator.  Example is for 9600.
    // See section 19.3.1 of datasheet.
    //  U2BRG = (Fcy/(16*BaudRate))-1
    //  U2BRG = (37M/(16*9600))-1
    //  U2BRG = 240
    U2BRG = 240;    // 40Mhz osc, 9600 Baud

    // Load all values in for U1STA SFR
    U2STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0; //Bit15 Int when Char is transferred (1/2 config!)
    U2STAbits.UTXINV = 0;   //Bit14 N/A, IRDA config
    U2STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0; //Bit13 Other half of Bit15
    //U2STAbits.notimplemented = 0; //Bit12
    U2STAbits.UTXBRK = 0;   //Bit11 Disabled
    U2STAbits.UTXEN = 0;    //Bit10 TX pins controlled by periph
    U2STAbits.UTXBF = 0;    //Bit9 *Read Only Bit*
    U2STAbits.TRMT = 0; //Bit8 *Read Only bit*
    U2STAbits.URXISEL = 0;  //Bits6,7 Int. on character recieved
    U2STAbits.ADDEN = 0;    //Bit5 Address Detect Disabled
    U2STAbits.RIDLE = 0;    //Bit4 *Read Only Bit*
    U2STAbits.PERR = 0;     //Bit3 *Read Only Bit*
    U2STAbits.FERR = 0;     //Bit2 *Read Only Bit*
    U2STAbits.OERR = 0;     //Bit1 *Read Only Bit*
    U2STAbits.URXDA = 0;    //Bit0 *Read Only Bit*

    IPC7 = 0x4400;  // Mid Range Interrupt Priority level, no urgent reason

    IFS1bits.U2TXIF = 0;    // Clear the Transmit Interrupt Flag
    IEC1bits.U2TXIE = 1;    // Enable Transmit Interrupts
    IFS1bits.U2RXIF = 0;    // Clear the Recieve Interrupt Flag
    IEC1bits.U2RXIE = 1;    // Enable Recieve Interrupts

    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;  // And turn the peripheral on

    U2STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
    // I think I have the thing working now.
}

void InitPorts() {
    // S3 (portD Pin 6, chosen as trigger for sending 'M' to UART)
    // S6 (portD Pin 7, chosen as trigger for sending 'C' to UART)
    // S5 (portA Pin 7, chosen as trigger for sending 'H' to UART)
    // S4 (portD Pin 13, chosen as trigger for sending 'P' to UART)

    TRISD = 0x20C0; // D6,7,13 inputs
    AD1PCFGHbits.PCFG23 = 1;    // This is important.  RA7 is muxxed with AN23,
        // So we need to config the pin as DIGITAL
    TRISA = 0x0080; // only 0th bit needs be output. A7 is input
    S3Flag = S4Flag = S5Flag = S6Flag = 0;  // Some Debounce Flags
}

void SoftwareDebounce() {
    if(PORTDbits.RD6 == FALSE) {
        if( S3Flag == FALSE ) {
            S3Flag = TRUE;
            U2TXREG = 'h';
        }
    }
    else {
        S3Flag = FALSE;
    }
    if(PORTDbits.RD7 == FALSE) {
        if( S6Flag == FALSE ) {
            S6Flag = TRUE;
            for(i=0; i<=4;i++){
                U2TXREG = ("%s", A[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        S6Flag = FALSE;
    }
    if(PORTAbits.RA7 == FALSE) {
        if( S5Flag == FALSE ) {
            S5Flag = TRUE;
            U2TXREG = '3';
        }
    }
    else {
        S5Flag = FALSE;
    }
    if(PORTDbits.RD13 == FALSE) {
        if( S4Flag == FALSE ) {
            S4Flag = TRUE;
            U2TXREG = '4';
        }
    }
    else {
        S4Flag = FALSE;
    }
}
int main(void) {

    InitClock();    // This is the PLL settings

    InitUART2();    // Initialize UART2 for 9600,8,N,1 TX/RX

    InitPorts();    // LEDs outputs, Switches Inputs

    while(1) {  // The ever versatile Infinite Loop!
        SoftwareDebounce();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, these changes should be a good start, but I imagine there's another register you need to block on before loading the next character to `U2TXREG`.  You should try to find a serial library to use so you can just pass the string(s) you want to print, and have them go into a circular buffer that an interrupt handler pulls from when the hardware is ready for the next byte.

```
const char *A = "hello how are";

if(PORTDbits.RD7 == FALSE) {
    if( S6Flag == FALSE ) {
        S6Flag = TRUE;
        int len = strlen(A);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            U2TXREG = A[i];
        }
    }
}
else {
    S6Flag = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I did that and it worked beautifully except it only sent hello instead of the entire string. any idea for this? Sorry, im very new at coding and got thrown into this for my senior project.

Comment: You only should write in the TX buffer when its empty. So test the buffer in advance and wait when its full.

Answer (score 0):

You only should write into the TX-Buffer, when there is at least one position empty, otherwise you will lost data:

```
const char *A = "hello how are";

if(PORTDbits.RD7 == FALSE) {
    if( S6Flag == FALSE ) {
        S6Flag = TRUE;
        int len = strlen(A);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            while (U2STAbits.UTXBF == 1);    //wait for an empty position in the buffer
            U2TXREG = A[i];
        }
    }
}
else {
    S6Flag = FALSE;
}
```